# Editable ComboBox in JavaFX: Works in NetBeans, doesn't work in JAR file

Tags: netbeans, javafx, jar, combobox

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboBoxSample extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    final Button button = new Button ("Send");
    final Label notification = new Label ();
    final TextField subject = new TextField("");
    final TextArea text = new TextArea ("");

    String address = " ";

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("ComboBoxSample");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 500, 270);

        final ComboBox emailComboBox = new ComboBox();
        emailComboBox.getItems().addAll(
            "jacob.smith@example.com",
            "isabella.johnson@example.com",
            "ethan.williams@example.com",
            "emma.jones@example.com",
            "michael.brown@example.com"  
        );

        final ComboBox priorityComboBox = new ComboBox();
        priorityComboBox.getItems().addAll(
            "Highest",
            "High",
            "Normal",
            "Low",
            "Lowest" 
        );   

        priorityComboBox.setValue("Normal");

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setVgap(4);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        grid.add(new Label("To: "), 0, 0);
        grid.add(emailComboBox, 1, 0);
        grid.add(new Label("Priority: "), 2, 0);
        grid.add(priorityComboBox, 3, 0);
        grid.add(new Label("Subject: "), 0, 1);
        grid.add(subject, 1, 1, 3, 1);            
        grid.add(text, 0, 2, 4, 1);
        grid.add(button, 0, 3);
        grid.add (notification, 1, 3, 3, 1);

        Group root = (Group)scene.getRoot();
        root.getChildren().add(grid);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }    
}
```

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/combo-box.htm#BABJCCIB

This code works just fine when I run it from NetBeans. However, there is a problem with a ComboBox when I run it from JAR file (both from CMD or folder view). Program ignores everything I type into the ComboBox, if the box was empty before editing, it displays "You have not selected a recipient!".
If a recipient from the list is selected and then edited, program ignores editing and sends it to the recipient.

I had the same problem with my own code, that's why I tested this code written by Oracle. I'm guessing there must be something wrong with NetBeans settings, but I have no idea what to do about that.

Comment: Is it possible your system Java version is different than the one NetBeans uses?  Try printing out `System.getProperty("java.version")` , and see if you get different results.

Comment: NetBeans version: 1.8.0_45
System version: 1.8.0_60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code like this:(Have and a look [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/0590__JavaFX_ComboBox.htm))

```
ComboBox emailComboBox = new ComboBox();
emailComboBox.setEditable(true);   //add this line
emailComboBox.getItems().addAll(
    "jacob.smith@example.com",
    "isabella.johnson@example.com",
    "ethan.williams@example.com",
    "emma.jones@example.com",
    "michael.brown@example.com"  
);

 ComboBox priorityComboBox = new ComboBox();
priorityComboBox.setEditable(true); //add this line
priorityComboBox.getItems().addAll(
    "Highest",
    "High",
    "Normal",
    "Low",
    "Lowest" 
);
```

**void javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.setEditable(boolean value)**

Sets the value of the property editable.
Property Description:Specifies whether the ComboBox allows for user input. When editable is true, the ComboBox has a text input area that a user may type in to. This input is then available via the value property. 
Note that when the editable property changes, the value property is reset, along with any other relevant state.

Comment: Somehow I posted wrong code here, I should have posted Example 16-4 from the link. After updating Java to JDK 1.8.0_91 everything works as expected.